# Url rewrite in web config

Tags: c#, .net, url, url-rewriting, web-config

edit1 : typo

edit2 : will donate a beer for help :)

I'm sorry if this question is noobish but I've tried following some tutorials and read some guides but I just can't get the hang of it.

We are switching domains as a result of building a new eCommerce and the URL's are quite different.

The old ones looks something like this:

```
olddomain.com/se/mycategory/subcategory/c/1234
```

{domain}/{language}/{c}/{id} are the important values and the categories/subcategories are not required for the url to work.

In the new environment however we do not use the c/id part, and the language part does not exist as well. Instead we have separate domains (like newdomain.com / newdomain.se etc).

I would like to use the url rewrite module to map the old url's based on id to the new url's.

```
<rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for test">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
                    <add input="{test:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="olddomain.com/(se|no|fi)/.+?(?=/c/)/c/(NI\d+|\d+)" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
</rules>

<rewriteMaps>
     <rewriteMap name="test" >
            <add key="olddomain.com/fi/c/34102" value="newdomain.fi/category"/>
     </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I type the url like this:

```
olddomain.com/fi/wada/wada/c/1234
```

In the IIS pattern tester i get this result:

```
c:0 olddomain.com/fi/wada/wada/c/1234
c:1 fi
c:2 1234
```

and if I test it on the development environment it doesn't even try to rewrite it.

What I'm looking for is for:

```
olddomain.com/fi/c/1234
```

to get sent down to the rewritemap and match the key for it, then rewrite to the new url.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong and if someone could explain this to me and help me out I'd really appreciate it

Thanks
/Fred

Comment: Is wadda/wadda representing controller/action?

Comment: wada/wada represents some stuff that just gets added in the url after category lookup, it serves no purpose other thanbeing friendly.